# Using ActiveRecord::Relations across models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with three models: Account, Package and Delivery.  I'm using AR::Relation scopes on Delivery to find recent deliveries and returns.  The Account model also needs to find accounts with recent deliveries.  **Can I use the same Delivery scopes in Account via `joins`?**  Right now I'm using code like this (note the duplication in `Account.with_recent_returns` and `Delivery.recent_returns`):

```
# Package(id: integer, ident: string)

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deliveries, :dependent => :destroy
end

# Delivery(id: integer, account_id: integer, delivered_on: date, package_id: integer, returned_on: date)`

class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :package

  scope :current, where(:returned_on => nil)

  scope :recent_deliveries, where('delivered_on >= ?', 2.weeks.ago)

  scope :recent_returns, where('returned_on >= ?', 2.weeks.ago)

  scope :returns, where('returned_on IS NOT NULL')
end

#  => Account(id: integer, name: string)

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :deliveries, :dependent => :destroy

  def self.with_current_deliveries
    joins(:deliveries).where(:deliveries => { :returned_on => nil } ).includes(:deliveries)
  end


  def self.with_recent_returns
    joins(:deliveries).where('deliveries.returned_on >= ?', 2.weeks.ago).includes(:deliveries)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this will work

`scope :recent_deliveries, joins(:deliveries).merge(Delivery.recent)`

or perhaps you'll need to use scoped

`scope :recent_deliveries, scoped.joins(:deliveries).merge(Delivery.recent)`

should get you started.